# Flask error: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound:

Tags: python, templates, flask, blueprint

I have a Flask project, `FlaskUserAuthentication` which has a package with same name(FlaskUserAuthentication) and under that package there are two more packages namely `API` and `Site`. The following is the structure-

[image]

Both the `__init__.py` files under the `API` and `Site` packages are empty.

The following is the code from `__init__.py` file under main `FlaskUserAuthentication` package, .

```
from flask import Flask
from API.routes import api
from Site.routes import site

app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(api)
app.register_blueprint(site)
```

and the `run.py` has following-

```
from FlaskUserAuthentication import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

However, when I enter `http://127.0.0.1:5000/index` after running the server, I get following error-

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html
```

When clearly I have the `index.html` file under `Site=>templates=>Site` folder. The following is my `Site=>routes.py` code-

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

site = Blueprint('Site', __name__, template_folder='templates') # updated


@site.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@site.route('/login')
def login():
    return render_template('login.html')
```

Can anyone please help.

P.S.: I have updated my solution and the question accordingly after some suggestions. Still same issue.

Comment: Be careful with your folder naming - there's a mismatch between `Site` and `site`. It's OK on a case insensitive filesystem, but you'll hit problems if you every try to run your code on a case sensitive filesystem (e.g. on Linux).

Comment: To debug the problem, set [`EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING), i.e. `app.config['EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING'] = True`.

Comment: I ran into the problem where is I had missed the last `s` in the name of template. The folder name where we store the flask template is strictly should be `templates` as per the [flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/templates/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as if you need to expose the templates by setting `template_folder`.

```
site = Blueprint('site', __name__, template_folder='templates')
```

See the [blueprints docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/blueprints/#templates) for more info. In particular you might want to consider creating the template at `Site/templates/Site/index.html` and using `render_template('Site/index.html')`, so that the template can't be accidentally overriden by another `index.html` in the app's templates directory.

Comment: I followed your suggestion but no luck. I added another folder named 'Site' under the templates folder and also updated the Blueprint instance creation. I updated my question with current screen shot.

Comment: You changed the layout but didn't switch to `render_template('Site/index.html')` at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

if your folder structure is `Site=>templates=>Site` then

```
@site.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('Site/index.html') #add Site folder name before index.html
```

Comment: Thank you but it was mentioned earlier by the previous author. You should not answer with the already suggested solution.